# Is it possible to conditionally divide numerous values across several columns?

Tags: excel

I have a dataset where I want to divide one value by another wherever a certain term appears in another column.

For example, wherever the value `LONDON` appears in `Column A`, I want to divide the value in the corresponding rows in `Column B` by the value in the corresponding rows in `Column C`.

So if rows 4, 5, and 6 all contain the value `LONDON`, then I want to divide the values in rows 4, 5, and 6 in `Column B` by the values in rows 4, 5, and 6 in `Column C` on a row-by-row basis.

For those curious why I want to do this: once done, I will take an average of all of the values, but I can do that and it isn't relevant within the scope of this question.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In cell D2, use this formula and copy down: `=IF(A2="LONDON",B2/C2,B2)`

Comment: =IF(Ai=”LONDON”,Bi/Ci,Bi)